# Longitude formatting/scale for calculating distance with geopy

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, geopy

I am using geopy to simply calculate the distance between two long,lat co-ordinates.

However I am confused on what scale the longitude should be on.

The latitude co-ordinated go from -90 to +90, and currently I've put my Longitude on a scale from 0-360 degrees  - should this be -180 to 180 to satisfy :

great_circle(NYC, test).miles

where NYC and test are the co-ord pairs.

Thanks,

Izzy

Answer (score 3):

Geopy [Point](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.14.0/#geopy.point.Point) latitude must be in range `[-90; 90]`, longitude should be in range `[-180; 180]`.

Longitude is automatically normalized (e.g. `185` is normalized to `-175`), while out-of-band latitudes would result in a `ValueError` being thrown. See the Point normalization testcases for getting the better idea on how normalization works: [test/test_point.py](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/e67a5bf389a5d7d99f3bf5e5a5aa1fdc011e22c3/test/test_point.py#L138)

An example [from docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.14.0/#module-geopy.distance) for calculating distance between two points:

```
>>> from geopy import distance
>>> newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
>>> cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
>>> print(distance.distance(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
538.39044536
```